# "cem" is not a supported method

Tags: propensity-score-matching

auto.match <- matchit(formula = Same_Race_Latinx ~ PC_age + Salary_Beg_unadjusted_BASE, data=data2, method = "cem")

Same_Race_Latinx is the treatment (same race as principal) and a numeric variable 0/1

Salary_Beg_unadjusted_BASE continuous variable (salary)

This is not my full list of covariates but I cannot get any of it to run without getting this "Error: "cem" is not a supported method."

I don't even know where to start with fixing this..

Answer (score 0):

This can simply be fixed by upgrading your version of `MatchIt`. If you were using `MatchIt` version 4.0.0, CEM was not supported. It is supported in more recent versions.